# How to download PDF file from AWS API gateway in python

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, base64, aws-api-gateway

I'm creating AWS API endpoint (GET) to get a PDF file and facing a serializable issue.

AWS Lambda is mapped to access the file from s3.

```
import boto3
import base64


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = client.get_object(
                Bucket='test-bucket',
                Key=file_path,
            )
    data = response['Body'].read()
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'isBase64Encoded': True,
        'body': data,
        'headers': {
            'content-type': 'application/pdf',
            'content-disposition': 'attachment; filename=test.pdf'
        }
    }
```

[ERROR] Runtime.MarshalError: Unable to marshal response: bytes is not JSON serializable.

If I `return str(data, "utf-8")` will download PDF file and making issues while open.

Please suggest to me where I'm lagging.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to initiate the client variable first and then encode the data that is coming back from s3 as followed:

```
import json
import boto3
import base64

client = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket_name ='bucket-name'
    file_name='file-name.pdf'
    
    fileObject = client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_name)
    
    file_content = fileObject["Body"].read()
    
    print(bucket_name, file_name)
    
    return base64.b64encode(file_content)
```